# Android emulator: editing init.rc file

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to learn Android `internals` and I've seen that boot process starts from `init.rc` file. I would like to know if there is a way to modify it when the emulator is off or it can be changed only while the emulator is up. In this case, I don't find a vi or similar text editor, so I must adb push the new file over the original, is it right?
Can anyone help me to find a way to edit `init.rc` file?

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late to answer but anyway:

If you want to replace the init.rc file by pushing a new edited file using adb you should have a root user permission to change the system from read only to read and write.

Another way is to download the source code of android x86 and then edit init.rc as you want then compile the code and build your own image of android x86. In this way you have the changes you did every time you install the image on any virtual machine.